# ng-if ... else - more readable version

Tags: angularjs

In my site I am using code like this:

```
span(class="item-org-panel-name", ng-repeat="org in organizationPath")
    a(href="", ng-if="! $last") {{ org.Name }}
    span(ng-if="$last") {{ org.Name }}
```

For all elements of collection I need to show `link` and I want to show `span` instead for last element.

I don't like my code becase it is not obvious that it is visible one an

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ng-switch` and `ng-switch-when`

```
span(class="item-org-panel-name", ng-repeat="org in organizationPath", ng-switch="$last")
    a(href="", ng-switch-when="true") {{ org.Name }}
    span(ng-switch-default) {{ org.Name }}
```

[ngSwitch](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSwitch)

Answer (score 0):

you can try this approach, using a directive:

```
app.directive('whatElementToUse', function($compile) {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: {
      name: '=',
      showAsSpan: '='
    },
    link: function(scope, elm, attr) {
      var tamplate = '';
      template = scope.showAsSpan ? '<span>{{name}}</span>' : '<a href="">{{name}}</a>';
      elm.html(template);
      $compile(elm.contents())(scope);
    }
  }
})
```

html:

```
<div ng-repeat="org in main.data" what-element-to-use name="org.name" show-as-span="$last"></div>
```

[plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/pQKM7z29ze5tps9XavHk?p=preview)